# Atlassian Confluence : Updating parent container of an attachment

Tags: confluence, confluence-rest-api

I'd like to move an attachment to a different space (i.e, update the parent container of an attachment in a Confluence page) using Cloud REST API and "curl" command. I looked up REST API endpoint URL and found this:

```
PUT /rest/api/content/{id}/child/attachment/{attachmentId}
```

Could somebody provide an example for a correctly constructed JSON input to achieve this? I tried the one below to move an attachment called "test.jpeg" with ID "att000" and current version 5 to parent with ID 1234, but it fails:

```
curl -v -u 'admin:password' -X PUT -H 'Content-Type:application/json' -d '{"id":"att000","type":"attachment","title":"test.jpeg","version":{"number":5,"minorEdit":false},"ancestors":[{"id":1234}]' -H ‘X-Atlassian-Token:access-token' https://test.atlassian.net/wiki/rest/api/content/170234/child/attachment | python -m json.tool
```

Given below is the error message

```
< HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type
.
.
.
No JSON object could be decoded
```

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I believe in your `curl` example you are uploading it under space which is not possible. Attachments in Confluence needs to be under content. Take a look at following example:

```
curl -v -S -u admin:admin -X POST -H "X-Atlassian-Token: no-check" -F "file=@myfile.txt" -F "comment=this is my file" "http://localhost:8080/confluence/rest/api/content/3604482/child/attachment" | python -mjson.tool
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Saleh. I corrected my JSON input, but I'm still unable to receive a response. I get "415 Unsupported Media Type" and "No JSON object could be decoded" errors.

Comment: Ah gotcha. Couple of questions, why you are not using post and you are using put? As well as I'm not seeing -F "file=@locationoffile" in your curl.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I would need to use "file=@locationoffile" for updating the binary data of the attachment. However, I'm trying to update only the non-binary data of an attachment (PUT instead of POST). Reference: https://docs.atlassian.com/atlassian-confluence/REST/latest/#content/{id}/child/attachment-update

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the `container` property in the request object.

Specify `"container":{"id":"123456","type":"attachment"}`

```
curl -v -u 'admin:password' -X PUT -H 'Content-Type:application/json' -d '{"id":"att000","type":"attachment","title":"test.jpeg","version":{"number":5,"minorEdit":false},"container":{"id":"123456","type":"attachment"}, "ancestors":[{"id":1234}]' -H ‘X-Atlassian-Token:access-token' https://test.atlassian.net/wiki/rest/api/content/170234/child/attachment | python -m json.tool
```

id => id of the page where attachment is being moved.